# How to test pushes with .p8 JWT Key? (APNs Auth Key)

Tags: ios, testing, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Since there are a lot of great apps (like [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) or [APNs Provider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification-service-testing-tool/id989622350?mt=12)) to test push notifications, they only support `.p12` or `.pem` certificates. How to test keys with `.p8` extension?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications if you want an existing application.

Answer (score 1):

You can test pushes with .p8 JWT Key via [OwnProvider](https://www.ownprovider.net)

Here is a macOS application which can be used to do this work too: https://www.angularcorp.com/post/macos-ownprovider